# jQuery toggle, close other elements when current one is open

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a menu that toggles when you click it, and hides the other menu's (if they are currently open). It works fine, however once you open the menu, it is not possible to close it.

Here is my jQuery code...

```
$(function() {
  $('.acctnav > li').click(function() {
    $('.acctnav ul').hide();
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();   
  });
});
```

Here is a link to the code pen... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yifmo

I would like to do the following...

1. When you click a menu link, it opens.
2. When you click a second link with the first menu still open, the first menu should close and the next menu is displayed.
3. Then when you click the second menu (currently open), this should now close.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i modified jquery code, check it :

```
$(function() {
  $('.acctnav > li').click(function() {
    $('.acctnav ul').hide();

    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();   


    });
});
```